# Why does my app get minimized without an obvious reason?

Tags: android, oneplustwo

**TL;DR**
My app gets minimized (as if the home-button was pushed) when I tap the navigation icon in my toolbar after going from an activity to another one and back.

Detailed flow of actions:

- Open app, Activity1 comes up
- Tap navigation icon (drawer opens normally, I can close and open it any amount of times at this stage, by pressing the navigation icon)
- Tap a drawer menu item which starts Activity2 with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`
- After Activity2 finishes loading, tap the navigation icon, drawer opens normally
- Tap the drawer menu item which starts Activity1 with the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` (at this point this Activity exists so is brought to front)
- After Activity1 is brought to front, tap navigation icon again to open the drawer
- Drawer starts sliding out from the left but app minimizes before it's out completely

I know the app is minimized because when I open it, Activity1 is on the screen with an open drawer

There's no Exception or log (level is at Verbose) and this happens only on a OnePlus Two (The app works fine on a Nexus 4)

Comment: I'm having similar issues. I think this is connected with FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT and happens only when there are 2 activities in the stack. It usually happens only on Vanilla Android (samsung devices don't have this problem AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to switch between 2 distinct stack. I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to handle `startActivity` and `finish()`.

But I have the same problem like you, it get minimized in one case:

Activity Class A (instance 1) -> open new Activity Class A (instance 2) -> Activty Class B -> switch to Activity Class A (instance 2) by `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, then `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to back to (instance 1) will minimized (go to background), but if I make it foreground back it did finish(), it just go to background by unknown reason.

It only happen if two class A instances on the stack continuously. I check the stack by `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'Window #'`

After I tried a lot of `FLAG` combination with no succeed, I come out with a hack idea, i.e. create a `Distinct` activity class.

While I already able to detect this is the same class on the stack (use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to push/pop the activity list stack), then when I want to back I simply call the `Distinct` class and make it `finish()` immediately in `onCreate()`. Then on the `finish()` code will `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` the class A instance 1. Since the Distinct class is not the same class of A, then it able to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` the instance 1 and close instance 2 just fine.

**[UPDATE]**

This answer actually buggy, but eventually I figure out the better way and write the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919137/1074998).