# How to fix app go to background after reorder to front and back

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-background, android-task

I currently managed to allow user switch between two distinct acitivties groups (let's said 4 activity classes A/B group and X/Y group) and switch by `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag, but I noticed there are some strange behaviour:

```
A ->(start activity)  X
X ->(reorder to front) A 
X , A ->(start) B ->(start) B2
A , B , B2 ->(reorder to front) X ->(start) Y
X , Y ->(reorder to front) A , B , B2 
X , Y , A , B <-(press back, app hide to background, B2 destroyed)  B2 
X , Y , A , B (click to foreground, B is here just fine)
```

How to prevent app hide to background when back from `B2` ?

I noticed it only happen in same class(`B` and `B2` is same class), if I use `B` and `C`, it will no such issue, I wanted to know what's the reason behind.

And `X ->(start) Y` is also the key to reproduce it.

I tried to use application-level custom instance list to detect `B2`'s `onPause()` and `isFinishing()` and `startActivty()` the `B`, but it will always calls `B`'s `onCreate()` even though using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`, which make me think this is not the proper solution. The proper solution should figure out how to prevent the app hide to background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstanding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag. I thought  activity Y `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`  activity C will retain the parent, so C backpress will go to B. No, this is not the case. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` actually make the C transfer to the new parent Y (i.e. the caller), but since parent Y is on top of C, so C backpress will not able goto Y and get minimized/hide to background.

I also misunderstanding my code create 2 stack, but actually it's only single stack. I must use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` to make it multple stacks.

I also need to define correct `launchMode` in manifest:

- Both launcher activity A and X must defined as `singleInstance` in
  manifest.
- Both home page activity B and Y must defined as `singleTop`
  in manifest.
- Other activities C and Z ...etc must defined as
  `singleTask` in manifest.

Activity A must set flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` when start home page B.
X should also set flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` when start home page Y.

If the tab task already started before, the valid flags to **loop** to reorder all the same task activities (store in global stack list) are (`moveTaskToBack(true);` single line also works but it not able back to foreground):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
                            |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

p/s: The above will not work in Android 5 and 6, which will only reorder single top activity to front, so I need to add `android.permission.REORDER_TASKS` in manifest and do this (More info, [see this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36986021#c2)):

```
ActivityManager tasksManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (final Activity a : YStackClasses) {
    if (IsBeforeAndroidNougat && (tasksManager != null)) {
        tasksManager.moveTaskToFront(a.getTaskId(), ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_NO_USER_ACTION); 
    } else { 
        //Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    }
}
```

If the tab task never started, should start launcher activity without set any special flag.

To prevent click launcher will refresh due to `singleInstance`, I must also do checking in A and B, put it before `setContentView` and `finish()`/`return;` early.

```
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    && getIntent().getAction() != null
    && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
    //figure out latest activity and it's home activity, and reorder to front, and its entire task stack will focus on top.
}
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` will no longer auto clear all activities to refresh the app, the solution is `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(desiredTask's Top Act);`, which will remove all activites below of top activitiy without affect the other task stack.

If the class is reuse, such as C1, C2, then I must use `startActivityForResult(intent, dummyResponse);` to force it create new acitivty on top of same class. But don't do it when A start activity B since `startActivityForResult` requires single task and ignore the `singleInstance` launchMode, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46174651/1074998). And don't do `ForResult` inside `onNewIntent()` which might causes page generated twice in stack (The second page not generated immediately, instead only generated when back). But I can do `ForResult` in the caller of `onNewIntent()` to take effect.

I also need to do this to make backpress work as expected in home activity to hide app and able back to the correct task page. I don't use `TASK_ON_HOME`(when start home page B class) flag because it's only single task direction (i.e. foreground to fixed activity instead of depends on previous top task activity):

```
@Override //B class
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true); //B task stack
    if (YStackClasses.size() > 0) { //Y task stack
        try {
            YStackClasses.get(0).moveTaskToBack(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And be careful the app stack might cache even though relaunch automatically due to crash, so sometime you need relaunch twice to make it back to initial stack state to test, or else you will get the wrong conclusion.

That's it, this answer might lack of code details, but it should help if you encounter  same **"hide to background when backpress"** problem like me, you can get idea of how difficult to achieve expected behavior if you set wrong flag in one step or defined wrong `launchMode` in one of the activity in manifest.